# Where can I find the NuGet package(s) for MongoDB required by Sitecore 8.1 (update 3)

Tags: nuget, mongodb

I've done an upgrade of Sitecore 8 to 8.1 update 3.
I notice that this version of Sitecore references version 1.10.0.62 of MongoDB.Bson and MongoDB.Driver. Where can I find these NuGet packages? I've looked on nuget.org but that only seems to have version 2 onward.

Comment: They are the in bin of your Sitecore zip file, aren't they? Do you need them as nuget packages?

Comment: Yep, I've got the DLLs themselves, I just need them in a package!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package was renamed on nuget, what you want is the `mongocsharpdriver` package. You can get 1.10.0.62 by using:

```powershell
Install-Package mongocsharpdriver -Version 1.10.0
```

That package contains boths `MongoDB.Driver.dll` and `MongoDB.Bson.dll`.

Here is the nuget page for the older project:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver/

Which has now been renamed to:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/